# Kentico 12 MVC ComponentDefinitionProvider Warning

Tags: model-view-controller, kentico

Does anyone know what the "ComponentDefinitionProvider" in K12 is and where I can disable this feature?
I do not use it and I get warnings in the event log. I would like to disable it to stop this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the errors logged are regarding license limitation and you are not using EMS edition. IF these two are correct, I am sorry for this trouble - it was a bug which was already fixed in [hotfix no. 4](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes)